# I have difficulty to understand the need of an owner for a Nib File what's the equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, wpf, xaml

The reason given by Apple is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html

> The reason this object is so important is that it is the main link
>   between your application code and the contents of the nib file. More
>   specifically, it is the controller object that is responsible for the
>   contents of the nib file.

Still I don't get it, what would be the analogy in C# and Winform or WPF/Xaml ?
What would happen internally if it didn't have an owner ?

Comment: I don't know C#, etc. But If you don't have owner then you can't access the elements(Label, Button..) of the NIB.

Comment: @Vijay I guess so but why ? C#/XAML does not have owner or at least it may not be called that way or is implicit so I'd like someone who knows both who could tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read all kind of explanations nothing really clear, in fact they make thing sound complicated.

The thing is I think, the xib View is not really a view until it is instantiated like for Winform or Xaml. So the file owner is just like the .cs behind a winform or a xaml file.

In .net instantiation is explicitly done in code generated by Visual Studio, whereas in ios you can't see the plumbing it's like black magic so the puzzle.